# Dynamically select text from div and set with mouseenter & mouseleave

Tags: jquery, html

I feel like my logic makes sense;  unfortunately, it doesn't :( ?
UPDATE: [livecode](http://www.designobvio.us/ie/)
**Question:**
*How can I on mouseenter grab `$(this).attr.('title')` and set that text to `('HGROUP h1')`'s  text?*

**jQuery**

```
$("div.box").on('mouseenter', function () { //select the box create mouseenter function
    var headerText = $(this).attr('title'); //get selected title and set to headerText
    $('HGROUP h1').text(headerText); //set hgroupd h1 text to headerText
});

$("div.box").on('mouseleave', function () { //select the box create mouseleave function
    $('HGROUP h1').text('DESIGNOBVIO.US'); //set the orginal text back in place on mouseleave
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="box">
<h1 title="can i haz it?2"></h1>
<div class="innerbox">
    <figure></figure>
    <ul class="categorySelect">
        <li class="misc"></li>
        <li class="print"></li>
        <li class="video"></li>
        <li class="web"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**Hgroup HTML**

```
<HGROUP>
 <h1>designobvio.us</h1>
 <h2>the colors duke, the colors!7</h2>
</HGROUP>
```

Any further explanation of where i went wrong would be awesome.

Comment: Also, you can simply use the `hover` function, `$('element').hover(function(){//mouse enter goes here },{ //mouseleave goes here }); `

Comment: I'm super super new to jQuery (at least tryign to write it myself) is there a hit on preformance using .on()? I really like using .on() b/c when said outloud as a sentance it's easier to make sense of.

Comment: @MatthewHarwood, In this case, it's almost the same thing(`.hover` uses `on` under the scenes), but it saves the second selector. use `hover` is it's more readable.

Comment: the `.on()` method is used for `Delegation`. When an object is not ready at the time of DOM `$(document).ready` (For example: loaded through Ajax). We must delegate the function down the chain. We start with a `parent element that is not dynamic`, such as a Table, for example. If that table `has rows that are added dynamically and have event functions associated with them` then we must use the jQuery `.on()` method. Such as `$('tableID').on('click', 'tr', function(){ //stuff here });` - This allows us to attach handlers to objects that don't exist. In this scenario, on is not needed.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy. This is only one use of `on` people think it's the only use, it's not... `$(...).click(fn)` internally calls `$(...).on('click', fn)`Please read the `on` docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
var headerText = $(this).attr('title');
```

To:

```
var headerText = $(this).find('h1').attr('title');
```

Your code is trying to get the title of div instead of it's `<h1>` child .

Comment: Ffff I feel dumb haha! is there a more symantic way to do this? you won either way. because of the explination

Comment: @MatthewHarwood. You can use `$(this).children('h1').attr('title');` or change the selector if it's possible. Anyway check the [`hover`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) event.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need to be using:

```
var headerText = $(this).find('h1:first').attr('title');
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use find to get title.

```
var headerText = $(this).find('h1').attr('title');
```

Try this :

```
  $("div.box").on('mouseenter', function () { 
 //select the box create mouseenter function
  var headerText = $(this).find('h1').attr('title'); 
  //get selected title and set to headerText
   console.log(headerText);
    $('HGROUP h1').text(headerText); //set hgroupd h1 text to headerText
 });

 $("div.box").on('mouseleave', function () { 
       //select the box create mouseleave function
     $('HGROUP h1').text('DESIGNOBVIO.US'); 
     //set the orginal text back in place on mouseleave
 });​
```

Here is [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9UfUy/)